# Tag badge progress

Tags: feature-request, badges, tag-badges, badge-progress

https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags

It would be nice if for each badge to have some indication as to how close you are to earning that badge.  Any chance of this being introduced?

Answer (score 16):

You can see your progress by hovering over the tag score in your profile:

> [image: screenshot of score]

Answer (score 10):

(Most) Stack sites now have a new profile setup, and we have two areas - Profile and Activity.

---

### Profile tab

[Your Profile tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) shows progress towards tags in a more structured and designed way.
This area is more a general summary and designed for other users viewing your profile (you can also see it).

- Your tag with the highest Score is listed on one row, with total
  Score, total Posts, and a percentage of total posts which contain
  that tag
- Then your next two highest scoring tags are listed on one row
  with Score and total Posts
- Then 3 tags are listed on one row, in descending Score order and
  total Score and Posts are shown for each tag
- Hovering over any part of the area which contains a tag (not just the
  Score) reveals a tooltip with additional information about wiki and
  non-wiki total answers and scores for that tag; Hovering over the tag
  itself shows the tag Excerpt;

[image: profile-tab-info]

---

---

### Activity tab

[Your Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) shows a summary of your 10 top tags listed in descending score order.
This area is designed more for your viewing than other users (other users can also see it).

- To the left of each tag is your total score for that tag
- To the right of each tag is the total number of posts you have
  participated in with that tag
- Hovering over the Score reveals a tooltip with additional information
  about wiki and non-wiki total answers and scores for that tag;
  Hovering over the total Post count confirms "*total X Posts in Y
  tag*"; Hovering over the tag itself shows the tag Excerpt;

[image: activity-tab-info]

---

### Viewing information on all your tags

Clicking on the "View all tags" link in your *Profile* tab and on "View more" link in your *Activity* tab both take you to the profile *Activity* tab with sub tab *tags* selected:

[All of your participation tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags)

This shows all tags in descending Score order which you have participated in, with total Score on the left and total Posts on the right for each individual tag.

Hovering here is the same as your main "Activity" tab:

- The Score reveals a tooltip with additional information about wiki
  and non-wiki total answers and scores for that tag
- The total Post count confirms "*total X Posts in Y tag*"
- The tag itself shows the tag Excerpt

Answer (score 1):

Some additional possibilities to find the number of (non-CW) answers and score in some tag:

- You can check the list of [top-users in a given tag](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/sheet-music/topusers). Even if you are not among the users with highest score, you'll be shown at the bottom of the list of top answers list - if you have at least one non-CW answer in that tag. (It works the same on any site - as an example I have used Music simply because there was recently a question about awarding tag badges on this site: [Tag badges awarded out of order: quirk or glitch?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357686).)
- You can use [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/1344986/my-score-and-number-of-non-cw-answers-per-tag?userid=70803) for this. (Keep in mind that the data in SEDE are updated only once a week. If you're new to Data Explorer, you can find pointers to additional information [in the tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info).)
- You can use badge tracker in your profile to see your progress towards various badges. To see tag badges, you have to choose tracking the next badge rather than the next privilege. Then you can click on "choose which badge to track" - and you'll be offered the table showing your progress to various badges. The screenshots are added below - I have combined the screenshots of the three steps into one picture.

[image: screenshots]