# How can I track my progress towards a tag badge?

Tags: support, tags, badges

A tag badge criterion says

> Earned X upvotes for at least Y answers in the Z tag

. How can I track this?

Comment: See [Tag badge progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62242/tag-badge-progress)

Comment: Although apparently the page layout has changed since then... the correct URL is now `http://SITE_NAME/tags/TAG_NAME/topusers` (if you're not in the top 30, you show up in 31st place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your profile and look at the tags section. The score to the left of each tag tells you how many upvotes you've earned (total upvotes - total downvotes) for that tag. Mouse over the number, and you will get a tooltip telling you how many votes you have for non-Community Wiki questions, for non-CW answers, and how many of each type of post you have.

Example:

[image]