# Tag badges awarded out of order: quirk or glitch?

Tags: support, tag-badges

1. About a week ago I hit the criteria for SE Music Practice & Theory's [sheet-music](/questions/tagged/sheet-music) bronze badge.
2. Yesterday I hit the criteria for the site's [harmony](/questions/tagged/harmony) bronze badge.
3. Today I received the [harmony](/questions/tagged/harmony) badge, but I have not yet received the [sheet-music](/questions/tagged/sheet-music) badge.

Is it a quirk of the tag-badge algorithm that badges might be awarded out of order? Was there a glitch that caused the [sheet-music](/questions/tagged/sheet-music) badge to get missed? Is there a tag-badge criterion I'm not aware of? Something else?

---

FWIW: My current [sheet-music](/questions/tagged/sheet-music) stats are 114 points on 21 posts. The tag itself has over 800 questions. My current [harmony](/questions/tagged/harmony) stats are 101 points on 38 posts. The tag has over 1000 questions.

Comment: See also the advice given here for checking on your progress towards tag badges: [Tag badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62242). I will also add SEDE queries showing for bronze badges [users with sufficient score - but missing answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/1230704/users-with-sufficient-score-for-a-tag-badge-missing-number-of-answers?minsco=100&mincount=20) and [the other way round](https://data.stackexchange.com/music/query/1230709/users-with-sufficient-number-of-answers-for-a-tag-badge-missing-on-score?minsco=100&mincount=20).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You did *not* hit the criteria for the [sheet-music](/questions/tagged/sheet-music) bronze badge.

The criteria for a tag bronze badge is the following:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

You currently have a score of 114 in the [sheet-music](/questions/tagged/sheet-music) tag. So, you pass the first criterion. You do **not**, however, pass the second one related to the number of posts.

To find out the number of posts that meet that criterion, you may use the following search query:

```
user:mine [sheet-music] is:answer wiki:0
```

You'll find out that you currently have 21 posts detailed as follows:

- [19 non-community-wiki answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A70803%20%5Bsheet-music%5D%20is%3Aanswer%20wiki%3A0).
- 1 question.
- 1 community-wiki answer.